# Infinite direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graded-rings

While reading about graded rings, I read that a graded ring $R$ is an infinite direct sum of abelian groups  $\displaystyle R=\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} A_i$
together with a  bilinear map $A_i\oplus A_j\longrightarrow A_{i+j}$.

I know that in the finite case we have that the direct sum of two abelian groups $A_1\oplus A_2$ is an abelian group and the addition is defined as $(a_1,a_2)+(a_1',a_2')=(a_1+a_1',a_2+a_2')$ but what if we take an **infinite** direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb Z} A_i$ of abelian groups, does the infinite case  give an abelian group and what an element in this infinite direct sum looks like and how do we add two elements together?

and my last question is that is it always possible to construct a bilinear multiplication $A_i\oplus A_j\longrightarrow A_{i+j}$ especially when the $A_i $ are not subgroups of the same group but rather they are completely disctinct abelian groups put together into an infinite direct sum. Thank you for your clarification !!

Comment: Do you know the definition of what a (possibly infinite) direct sum is? If not, read it, and perhaps you'll be able to answer your own question!

Comment: yes I know the finite case and I gave it in my post but can't figure out what an infinite case should be

Answer (score 4):

It is simply the subgroup of all elements $(a_i)$ in the product $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in\mathbf Z}A_i$ such that all $a_i$ are $0$ but a finite number.

You may think of the construction of the ring of polynomials  with coefficients in $R$; it is the  $R^{(\mathbf N)}$ of sequences of coefficients  almost all $0$.

Comment: Thank you bernard, for example how can we write $R [X]$ as an infinite sum of abelian groups ?

Comment: $R[X]=\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbf N}RX^i$.

Comment: do you mean $RX^i$ is the abelian group of polynomials of degree **less or equal** to $i$ ? because the set of polynomials of degree exactly $i$ is not a group.

Comment: No it's the set of monomials of degree $i$, plus $0$.

Comment: ah ok i see ! this is an ablian group.. what about writing $R[X]=\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N} A_i$ with $A_i$ being the abelian group of polynomials of degree less or equal to $i$, does this give a grading on the polynomial ring ?

Comment: No, it's not a direct sum. But it defines a *filtration*, if you've seen this term, and to each filtered group/ring,  a graded group/ring can be  associated.

Comment: Dear @Bernard, following wikipedia it is a direct sum : "The direct sum of abelian groups is a prototypical example of a direct sum. Given two abelian groups $(A, \circ)$ and $(B, \bullet)$, their direct sum$A \oplus B$ is the same as their direct product of groups, that is the underlying set is the Cartesian product $A \times B$ and the group operation $\cdot$ is defined component-wise:
$(a_1, b_1) \cdot (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 \circ a_2, b_1 \bullet b_2)$."

Comment: I think I see,  you mean that the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N}A_i$ is of course a direct sum and it is included in $R[X]$ but it does not cover all of $R[X]$ . Could you please give me an element in $R[X]$ that is not in $\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb N}A_i$.. Thank you !!

Comment: @palio: The Wikipedia information is only about finite direct sums: in the category of abelian groups, it is the same as a finite product. For infinite direct sums, one has to add the condition that all components but a finite number are $0$.

Comment: For your last comment: no,  the  sum of the $ A_i$s is indeed the whole of $R[X]$, but it is *not* a direct sum, since $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$.

Comment: I thought given the abelian groups $A_i$s I can always take their direct sum, even if $A_i=A_j$ I saw many times the direct sum $\mathbb  R \oplus \mathbb R$.. now if I'm following you well you are saying if there is intersection like here $A_i\subset A_{i+1}$ we can not take their direct sum..

Comment: That is an *external* direct sum. You always can take the external direct sum of modules, but it  is not the internal  direct sum of submodules.

Comment: Oh i see, and grading of a ring $(R,+,.)$ is about writing $R$ as an **internal** direct sum of subgroups $(A_i,+)$ of the additive abelian group $(R,+)$, is that correct ?

Comment: It's exactly that.